# Why does adding ArrayList<object> inside another ArrayList<obj> replaces values of inner ArrayList<obj> at previous position

Tags: android, list, object, arraylist

I have two ArrayLists of object (let's say alOuter & alInner)-

```
ArrayList<ObjectName>alOuter=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ObjectName>alInner=new ArrayList<>();
```

I need to add the alInner in alOuter like-

```
alOuter.add(new ObjectName("some value",alInner));
```

This works fine here but when I add the alInner for second time or forth, the values of alInner inside alOuter at previous positions are replaced with the current values of alInner.

like-

```
alInner.add(new ObjectName("1","A"));
alOuter.add(new ObjectName("some value",alInner));

alInner.clear();
alInner.add(new ObjectName("2","B"));
alOuter.add(new ObjectName("some value",alInner));

alInner.clear();
alInner.add(new ObjectName("3","C"));
alOuter.add(new ObjectName("some value",alInner));
```

Now the values in alOuter at every position is-

```
"some value",("3","C")
```

Why does it replace the values at previous positions?
Is there any other way to add ArrayList inside another ArrayList ?

Comment: Because there's only one `allInner` object. You keep adding values to the same object.

Comment: but I have added them to alOuter so I don't  need the alInner anymore but once they are added in alOuter that value should exist in alOuter. Howcome the previos values inside alOuter are replaced

Comment: Adding an object to another object doesn't automagically duplicate it. It's still the same object, no matter how many lists you put it into.

Comment: Is there any substitute for it or a workaround? How can I use a list inside another list?

Comment: Instead of doing `allInner.clear()`, do `allInner = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: I'll try and get back. I'm not sure that will work

Comment: That works fine. thank you @ Robby Cornelissen. Post that answer so that I can accept that

Comment: Someone else already posted it.

Comment: yeah thanks by the way for your early response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add `alInner` into `alOuter`, you are not passing a copy. You are adding the same array list into `alOuter` multiple times. I can see that you attempted to clear the array list before adding it to `alOuter` again. However, this does not create a new array list. So as soon as you cleared `alInner`, `alOuter`'s array lists will appear to have been changed. To fix this, you need to create new array lists using `new`:

```
alInner = new ArrayList<>(); // do this in place of clear.
```

Alternatively,

```
// this copies the stuff inside alInner to a new array list
alOuter.add(new ObjectName("some value",new ArrayList<>(alInner)));
```

As you can see, you must use `new` to create a new object in this case, because objects don't usually create themselves automatically when you pass them around. That's what value types do.

Comment: That works fine  Robby Cornelissen had suggested the same solution

Comment: @SAurabh Yes, and I also added an alternative approach and some explanation as to why this behaviour occurs.